# How to make a variable Pascal case in mod rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite

`mysite.com/vehicle/car/honda` to `mysite.com/vehicles.php?type=car&brand=Honda`.

I have written this.

`RewriteRule ^vehicle/(.+)/(.+)$ vehicles.php?type=$1&brand=$2 [NC,L]`

This works fine. But as you can see, this doesn't convert `honda` to `Honda`. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: I would recommend to rethink whether it is a good idea to try to implement this based on rewriting. rewriting operates on protocol level, it deals with transferring data somewhere and controls the flow. What you ask for is manipulation of that data, so processing. That is something that should not be done on protocol level but inside your application logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will handle this in my app logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unless you write your own module to extend limited internal Apache functions.

Source : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int

How is your web server supposed to know `.../car/hondacivic` should become `...&brand=HondaCivic` (Pascal case) anyway?

Possible work-around :

1) Either make sure your initial link is `mysite.com/vehicle/car/Honda` (capital H) so that it becomes `...&brand=Honda` ...

2) ... or just assign `<?php $brand = ucfirst($_GET['brand']); ?>` in your php file.

Not sure how important it is for you apart from the esthetic (pretty sure it does not matter at all SEO-wise).

Comment: To answer your question, I think I used the wrong word here. It's not Pascal I want, but just to make the first character uppercase. I just wanted to see if I can do this without changing the app code. But looking at your answer it seems I'll have to go with option 2. Thank you.